# app working good o local host but not on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have a simple app where user A can add offers and user B can generate coupons for these offers, I don't know anything about coding and stuff so i hired a programmer who had created this system for me, everything was working great but then i integrated AWS in my app and suddenly the generate coupon button stopped working, it works fine on Localhost but not on heroku, my programmer is not here right now.

whenever i click on the button **Generate Coupon For This Offer**
it takes me to a page saying:

```
The page you were looking for doesn't exist.

    You may have mistyped the address or the page may have moved.

    If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.
```

i checked the heroku logs:

```
2016-05-06T04:10:50.409337+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/offer
s/3/generate_coupon" host=www.taponomics.com request_id=e130f6c2-62c6-4a68-a4b8-
97daba3653ac fwd="103.51.151.184" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=8ms status=404
bytes=1829
2016-05-06T04:10:50.406339+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/offers/3/generate_cou
pon" for 103.51.151.184 at 2016-05-06 04:10:50 +0000
2016-05-06T04:10:50.408178+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No
route matches [GET] "/offers/3/generate_coupon"):
2016-05-06T04:10:50.408164+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-05-06T04:10:50.408181+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rai
lties-4.2.3/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
2016-05-06T04:10:50.408184+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rai
lties-4.2.3/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
2016-05-06T04:10:50.408181+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rai
lties-4.2.3/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
2016-05-06T04:10:50.408186+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rac
k-1.6.4/lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
2016-05-06T04:10:50.408184+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/act
ivesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
2016-05-06T04:10:50.408180+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/act
ionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
2016-05-06T04:10:50.408187+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/act
ionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:116:in `call'
2016-05-06T04:10:50.408179+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/act
ionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
2016-05-06T04:10:50.408189+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rai
lties-4.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
2016-05-06T04:10:50.408185+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/act
ionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
2016-05-06T04:10:50.408188+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rac
k-1.6.4/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
2016-05-06T04:10:50.408182+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/act
ivesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
2016-05-06T04:10:50.408183+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/act
ivesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
2016-05-06T04:10:50.408186+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rac
k-1.6.4/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
2016-05-06T04:10:50.408192+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rac
k-1.6.4/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in `service'
2016-05-06T04:10:50.408190+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rac
k-1.6.4/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
2016-05-06T04:10:50.408194+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/
webrick/server.rb:294:in `block in start_thread'
2016-05-06T04:10:50.408189+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rai
lties-4.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
2016-05-06T04:10:50.408191+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rac
k-1.6.4/lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
2016-05-06T04:10:50.408192+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/
webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
2016-05-06T04:10:50.408193+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/
webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
2016-05-06T04:10:50.408195+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-05-06T04:10:50.408195+00:00 app[web.1]:
```

**My app Modal**
*offers.rb*

```
class Offer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: "1280x720#" }, :default_url => "missing.jpg"
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

  def generate_coupon
    coupon = random_coupon
    loop do
      break unless Offer.match_coupon?(coupon)
      coupon = random_coupon
    end
    coupon
  end

  private

  def self.match_coupon?(coupon)
    where(coupon: coupon).present?
  end

  def random_coupon
    'CODE' + rand((1111..9999)).to_s
  end
end
```

**My app Controller**
*offers_controller.rb*

```
class OffersController < InheritedResources::Base

  def generate_coupon
    @offer = Offer.find(params[:id])
    @offer.update_attributes(coupon: @offer.generate_coupon) if @offer.coupon.blank?
  end

  private

    def offer_params
      params.require(:offer).permit(:name, :deal, :services, :address, :coupon, :image)
    end
end
```

**My app index page**
*index.html.erb*

```
<head>
    <link href="/assets/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/assets/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/assets/offers.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="text-center">
    <h1>offers Around You</h1>
  </div>
  <p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
  <% @offers.each do |offer| %>
    <div class="wrap ">
      <h1><%= offer.name %></h1>
      <h6><%= image_tag offer.image.url(:medium)%></h6>
      <div class="text-center">
        <h6> <%= offer.deal %></h6>
        <%= button_to "View Details", offer, :method => "get", class: "btn btn-success" %>
      </div>
      <%klass = offer.coupon.blank? ? '' : 'offer-display'%>
      <div class="row <%=klass%>" id="offer-<%=offer.id%>">
        <% if offer.coupon.blank?%>
          <%= link_to "Generate Coupon For This Offer", generate_coupon_offer_path(offer), method: :post, class: "btn btn-success", style: "margin-top: 20px; color: #fff", remote: true %>
        <% else %>
          <%= offer.coupon %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
</body>
```

**generate_coupon.js.erb**

```
$("#offer-<%=@offer.id%>").addClass('offer-display')
$("#offer-<%=@offer.id%>").html("<%=@offer.coupon%>")
```

**My Routes**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :offers do
    get '/offers/:id', to: 'offers#show'
    member do
      post 'generate_coupon'
    end
  end
end
```

**Updated log after dkp answer**

```
2016-05-06T04:28:59.463133+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missin
g template offers/generate_coupon, inherited_resources/base/generate_coupon, app
lication/generate_coupon with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[],
 :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :arb, :jbuilder]}. Searched i
n:
2016-05-06T04:28:59.463134+00:00 app[web.1]:   * "/app/app/views"
2016-05-06T04:28:59.463135+00:00 app[web.1]:   * "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/
gems/activeadmin-1.0.0.pre2/app/views"
2016-05-06T04:28:59.463136+00:00 app[web.1]:   * "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/
gems/mailboxer-0.13.0/app/views"
2016-05-06T04:28:59.463137+00:00 app[web.1]:   * "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/
gems/devise-3.5.9/app/views"
2016-05-06T04:28:59.463136+00:00 app[web.1]:   * "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/
gems/kaminari-0.16.3/app/views"
2016-05-06T04:28:59.463140+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/act
ionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view/lookup_context.rb:121:in `find'
2016-05-06T04:28:59.463138+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
2016-05-06T04:28:59.463139+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/act
ionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view/path_set.rb:46:in `find'
2016-05-06T04:28:59.463148+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/act
ionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:8:in `render'
2016-05-06T04:28:59.463149+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/act
ionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
2016-05-06T04:28:59.463141+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/act
ionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:18:in `find_template
'
2016-05-06T04:28:59.463141+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/act
ionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:40:in `determine_tem
plate'
2016-05-06T04:28:59.463152+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/act
ionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:32:in `render_to_body'
2016-05-06T04:28:59.463151+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/act
ionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:217:in `_render_template'

2016-05-06T04:28:59.463150+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/act
ionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
2016-05-06T04:28:59.463150+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/act
ionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:100:in `_render_template'
2016-05-06T04:28:59.463152+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/act
ionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:83:in `render_to_body'
2016-05-06T04:28:59.463153+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/act
ionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:37:in `render_to_body'
2016-05-06T04:28:59.463153+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/act
ionpack-4.2.3/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:25:in `render'
2016-05-06T04:28:59.463155+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/act
ionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in `block (2 lev
els) in render'
2016-05-06T04:28:59.463154+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/act
ionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
2016-05-06T04:28:59.463156+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/act
ivesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
2016-05-06T04:28:59.463156+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/
benchmark.rb:303:in `realtime'
2016-05-06T04:28:59.463157+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/act
ivesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
2016-05-06T04:28:59.463158+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/act
ionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:87:in `cleanup_view
_runtime'
2016-05-06T04:28:59.463157+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/act
ionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in `block in ren
der'
2016-05-06T04:28:59.463159+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/act
iverecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in `cleanup_
view_runtime'
2016-05-06T04:28:59.463159+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/act
ionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:43:in `render'
2016-05-06T04:28:59.463160+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/act
ionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_rend
er'
2016-05-06T04:28:59.463161+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/act
ionpack-4.2.3/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
2016-05-06T04:28:59.463160+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/act
ionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'
2016-05-06T04:28:59.463162+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/act
ionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
2016-05-06T04:28:59.463163+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/act
ivesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:115:in `call'
2016-05-06T04:28:59.463162+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/act
ionpack-4.2.3/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_actio
n'
2016-05-06T04:28:59.463168+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/act
ivesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:553:in `block (2 levels) in com
pile'
2016-05-06T04:28:59.463168+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/act
ivesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:115:in `call'
2016-05-06T04:28:59.463169+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/act
ivesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:503:in `call'
2016-05-06T04:28:59.463169+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/act
ivesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:503:in `call'
2016-05-06T04:28:59.463174+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/act
ionpack-4.2.3/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
2016-05-06T04:28:59.463174+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/act
ivesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `run_callbacks'
2016-05-06T04:28:59.463175+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/act
ionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
2016-05-06T04:28:59.463175+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/act
ionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in pro
cess_action'
2016-05-06T04:28:59.463177+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/act
ivesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrum
ent'
2016-05-06T04:28:59.463176+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/act
ivesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument
'
2016-05-06T04:28:59.463177+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/act
ivesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
2016-05-06T04:28:59.463178+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/act
ionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_acti
on'
2016-05-06T04:28:59.463178+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/act
ionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_acti
on'
2016-05-06T04:28:59.463179+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/act
iverecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_
action'
2016-05-06T04:28:59.463180+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/act
ionpack-4.2.3/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
2016-05-06T04:28:59.463180+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/act
ionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
2016-05-06T04:28:59.463181+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/act
ionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
2016-05-06T04:28:59.463181+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/act
ionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
2016-05-06T04:28:59.463182+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/act
ionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:237:in `block in action'
2016-05-06T04:28:59.463182+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/act
ionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:76:in `call'
2016-05-06T04:28:59.463183+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/act
ionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:76:in `dispatch'
2016-05-06T04:28:59.463183+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/act
ionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:45:in `serve'
2016-05-06T04:28:59.463184+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/act
ionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
2016-05-06T04:28:59.463184+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/act
ionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
2016-05-06T04:28:59.463185+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/act
ionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
2016-05-06T04:28:59.463185+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/act
ionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:821:in `call'
2016-05-06T04:28:59.463186+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/war
den-1.2.6/lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
2016-05-06T04:28:59.463187+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/war
den-1.2.6/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
2016-05-06T04:28:59.463188+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rac
k-1.6.4/lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
2016-05-06T04:28:59.463188+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rac
k-1.6.4/lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
2016-05-06T04:28:59.463187+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/war
den-1.2.6/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
2016-05-06T04:28:59.463189+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rac
k-1.6.4/lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
2016-05-06T04:28:59.463190+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/act
ionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
2016-05-06T04:28:59.463190+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/act
ionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
2016-05-06T04:28:59.463191+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rac
k-1.6.4/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
2016-05-06T04:28:59.463191+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rac
k-1.6.4/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
2016-05-06T04:28:59.463192+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/act
iverecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
2016-05-06T04:28:59.463193+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/act
iverecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.r
b:653:in `call'
2016-05-06T04:28:59.463192+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/act
ionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
2016-05-06T04:28:59.463194+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/act
ionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
2016-05-06T04:28:59.463194+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/act
ivesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:84:in `run_callbacks'
2016-05-06T04:28:59.463195+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/act
ionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
2016-05-06T04:28:59.463195+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/act
ionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
2016-05-06T04:28:59.463204+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/act
ionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
2016-05-06T04:28:59.463206+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rai
lties-4.2.3/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
2016-05-06T04:28:59.463205+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/act
ionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
2016-05-06T04:28:59.463206+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rai
lties-4.2.3/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
2016-05-06T04:28:59.463207+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/act
ivesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
2016-05-06T04:28:59.463207+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/act
ivesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
2016-05-06T04:28:59.463209+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/act
ionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
2016-05-06T04:28:59.463209+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rai
lties-4.2.3/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
2016-05-06T04:28:59.463208+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/act
ivesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
2016-05-06T04:28:59.463210+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rac
k-1.6.4/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
2016-05-06T04:28:59.463210+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rac
k-1.6.4/lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
2016-05-06T04:28:59.463211+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/act
ionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:116:in `call'
2016-05-06T04:28:59.463211+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rac
k-1.6.4/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
2016-05-06T04:28:59.463212+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rai
lties-4.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
2016-05-06T04:28:59.463212+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rai
lties-4.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
2016-05-06T04:28:59.463213+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rac
k-1.6.4/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
2016-05-06T04:28:59.463215+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/
webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
2016-05-06T04:28:59.463214+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rac
k-1.6.4/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in `service'
2016-05-06T04:28:59.463214+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rac
k-1.6.4/lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
2016-05-06T04:28:59.463220+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/
webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
2016-05-06T04:28:59.463221+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/
webrick/server.rb:294:in `block in start_thread'
2016-05-06T04:28:59.463222+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-05-06T04:28:59.463221+00:00 app[web.1]:
```

**application.js**

```
//= require bootstrap
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-1.11.1
//= require jquery.easing.min

//= require_tree .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Logs:**

```
2016-05-06T04:10:50.406339+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/offers/3/generate_cou
pon" for 103.51.151.184 at 2016-05-06 04:10:50 +0000
2016-05-06T04:10:50.408178+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No
route matches [GET] "/offers/3/generate_coupon"):
```

You are making a `GET` request but you have specified in your route to serve a `POST` request.

**EDIT**

Your `OffersController` `generate_coupon` action actually updating attributes, so kindly change your route to `put` (see my below changes for routes):

**routes**

```
resources :offers do
  get '/offers/:id', to: 'offers#show'
  member do
   put 'generate_coupon'
  end
end
```

Add `method: :put` to your `link_to`:

```
<%= link_to "Generate Coupon For This Offer", generate_coupon_offer_path(offer), method: :put, class: "btn btn-success", style: "margin-top: 20px; color: #fff", remote: true %>
```

In order to deal with the `ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missin
g template offers/generate_coupon` issue,

just make sure you have the corresponding template in `views/offers/generate_coupon.js.erb`

**application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery.easing.min
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: no now it's giving error **We're sorry, but something went wrong**

i have added the updated logs after applying your answer @dkp

Comment: @AhmedRezaSiddique please check the EDIT I have added to the answer

Comment: No it didn't worked but with your previous answer it started showin the coupon code but only after the error... means first it give the error and when i refresh it gives the coupon code @dkp

i don't have **generate_coupon.html.erb** but instead of that i have **generate_coupon.js.erb**

Comment: @AhmedRezaSiddique What error you are getting now ?

Comment: **We're sorry, but something went wrong**
i remember when it used to work it doesn't go to any page instead of that it shows the result in realtime on the same page @dkp

Comment: @AhmedRezaSiddique please review my answer once again and make sure everything in place and check Heroku logs if you are seeing any different error

Comment: it's giving the same error i checked the heroku logs:
**2016-05-06T05:14:10.574991+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/offers/7/generate_cou
pon" for 103.51.151.184 at 2016-05-06 05:14:10 +0000
2016-05-06T05:14:10.576444+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-05-06T05:14:10.576454+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No
route matches [GET] "/offers/7/generate_coupon"):**
@dkp

Comment: @AhmedRezaSiddique can you show your updated `link_to` as I have mentioned in the answer

Comment: **<%= link_to "Generate Coupon For This Offer", generate_coupon_offer_path(offer), method: :put, class: "btn btn-success", style: "margin-top: 20px; color: #fff", remote: true %>**

@dkp

Comment: @AhmedRezaSiddique Not sure why it is making a `GET` request even after specifying `method: :put`,   are sure you are modifying the correct template ?

Comment: i have already mentioned the file **generate_coupon.js.erb** in my question you can checkit out or you can directly check the website http://www.taponomics.com/offers
@dkp please check it out

Comment: `//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs` - do you have these `require`s mentioned in your `application.js` ?

Comment: hey @dkp thanks for your help...i have updated my question with application.js...please have a look sir

Comment: @AhmedRezaSiddique You are not loading jQuery library on this page. That is why `jquery_ujs` unable to detect `data-method = "put" ` from your generated HTML and also your `remote: true` is not working. Due to this, always it makes the default `GET` request.

Comment: hey sir @dkp can you please tell me how to load the jQuery library on the page... as i don't know much about it now

Comment: @AhmedRezaSiddique I have added the `application.js` to answer, you should `require` your js files in that order. And, if you have `gem 'jquery-rails'` mentioned in your `Gemfile`, then you do not need to add another `//= require jquery-1.11.1` to your `application.js`

Answer (score 0):

Do the job in two separate methods. One for showing the data and other for updating the records.

```
def show
      @offer = Offer.find(params[:id])
end

def create
     @offer.update_attributes(coupon: @offer.generate_coupon) if  
     @offer.coupon.blank?
end
```

And change that js file to `create.js.erb` .
Just make things clear and separate the methods from resources and see if it's working perfectly. Let me know the progress.